# replicating the behavior of FF "screenshot node" with js

Tags: javascript, firefox, screenshot, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there a way to replicate the behavior of Firefox "screenshot node" option in the dom inspector with js?

So I could select an element and do something like:

```
elem = document.getElementById("something");
screenshot = elem.takeScreenshot("image/png");
//screenshot: base64 encoded image string
```

Maybe with the built in Firefox function ?
[image: Firefox "screenshot node" function]

If not, is there a way to access it or do it from the addon-sdk ?

Kind regards,
Flo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots

Comment: @mplungjan ok I should have added this, I tried HTML2Canvas but like it is stated the css render support is limited, and images are only loadable with a proxy because of CORS

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by computing the bounding box of the node and then using the privileged [CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawWindow) API